# Azure: Configure Authentication/Authorization for API App. Express config, app not found

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azureportal

I'm trying to configure AAD Authentication for an API App. So:

1. I go to AAD, App Registrations, New application registration, and
   **register a new app foo-webapi**:

[image]

2. Go to API app, **Authentication/Authorization**, Click 'On'; select
   'Log in with Azure Active Directory', click Azure Active Directory
   Authentication Provider

[image]

3. In AAD Configuration, click 'Express', click 'Select Existing AD
   App', and **search for foo-webapi, and none is found**

[image]

4. I try creating it just in case!?, but it obviously **complains of an
   existing app** with that name

[image]

Could anyone please help in making sense of this?

*Note: I'm aware of the fact that I can create it directly from here, rather than do it previously, but authentication won't work in this fashion, which will probably be my next question, but this fact I'm describing is a symptom that I don't completely understand these features.*

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure authentication for your application, please follow the **[Manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication#a-nameadvanced-aalternative-method-manually-configure-azure-active-directory-with-advanced-settings)** approach mentioned here. I have done this to my App service and its working fine.

Comment: Thanks. I've done so already. But I want to understand whether there's something I'm configuring incorrectly and why it makes sense, or whether it's just a bug.

Comment: Sorry  but it doesn't address the question about why is this behavior